# Autofac Container Independence and Relationship Types

Tags: dependency-injection, ioc-container, autofac

We are currently using Autofac as our chosen IoC container. All application code in our reusable assemblies must be kept as clean as possible, so we do not want any direct dependencies on Autofac in our core application. The only place where Autofac is permitted is in the composition root / bootstrappers, where components are registered and wired up. Applications rely on dependency injection to create the required object graphs.

As we are keeping our core application container agnostic, it means that we cannot use the Autofac relationship types, such as `Owned`, in our core application.

I would like to create a factory that returns components that implement `IDisposable`. As Autofac tracks disposable objects, I believe I have to use a lifetime scope to create a defined unit of work in which components will be disposed once they go out of scope.

According to the Autofac documentation, this can be achieved by taking a dependency on `Func<Owned<T>>`, however, as stated above, I cannot take a dependency on `Owned` as it is an Autofac type. At the bottom of [this](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/RelationshipTypes) page, it says

> The custom relationship types in Autofac don’t force you to bind your application more tightly to Autofac. They give you a programming model for container configuration that is consistent with the way you write other components (vs. having to know a lot of specific container extension points and APIs that also potentially centralise your configuration.)
>
> For example, you can still create a custom ITaskFactory in your core model, but provide an AutofacTaskFactory implementation based on `Func<Owned<T>>` if that is desirable.

It is this implementation of `ITaskFactory` that I believe I need to implement, but I cannot find any examples.

I would be very grateful if someone could provide such an example.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best "real-world" example of this is the Autofac MVC integration mechanism. While it doesn't use `Func<Owned<T>>` under the covers it does show you how you might be able to implement a non-Autofac-specific mechanism to talk to Autofac under the covers.

In the MVC case, the `System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver` is the interface and the `Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacDependencyResolver` is the implementation. When ASP.NET MVC requests a service, it gets it from `System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.Current`, which returns an `IDependencyResolver`. At app startup, that singleton gets set to the Autofac implementation.

The same principle could hold for your custom factory. While `IDependencyResolver` is not specific to the type it returns (it's just `GetService<T>()`) you could write a type-specific factory interface just as easily.